# laravel storage is not writing the right content into the file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

I have a server url of my sql dump file. 
I am passing that into my code to download the server file into my local project directory. It is not saving the sql content into my file. It is saving file url as content.

```
$fullPath = 'http://www.server.com/api/sql/L2hvbWUvdmFncmFudC9jb2RlL2N5YmV4L2RhdGFiYXNlL2R1bXBzL2N5YmV4IG15c3FsIDIwMTgtMDctMjcgMDgtNDQtMjMgY2M0MjU5MGY4NzdhZjAzY2UxNjZkYWQwZGM1NzI1M2RmOWE5NTZjNy5zcWw=';    

public function fileDownload($fullPath) 
{    
    $url     = $fullPath;
    $content = file_get_contents($url);

    Storage::disk('snapshots')->put('mysqldump.sql', $content);          
}
```

How do I download the file itself and store in my snapshot directory?

Comment: is your url accessible publicly ?

Comment: @ kerbholz quotes and ; is there in my code. no syntax errors

Comment: @rkj no its not. I m calling the api to generate a sql file on server directory and returning me the path as http://..... to download the file. $fullpath is the http path to download the file.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `$contents = file_get_contents(file_get_contents($url));`?

Comment: @Codebugggs when you get url to download then check does it download from browser if not then `file_get_contents` can't fetch its content

Comment: error: file_get_contents(L2hvbWUvdmFncmFudC9jb2RlL2N5YmV4L2RhdGFiYXNlL2R1bXBzL2N5YmV4IG15c3FsIDIwMTgtMDctMjcgMDgtNDQtMjMgY2M0MjU5MGY4NzdhZjAzY2UxNjZkYWQwZGM1NzI1M2RmOWE5NTZjNy5zcWw=): failed to open stream: No such file or directory